# Python: Add column to groupby-result containing size of each group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I grouped a data frame to get this:

```
+------+----+-------+
| Type | Nr | Class |
+------+----+-------+
| One  | 01 | A1    |
| One  | 01 | A2    |
| One  | 01 | B1    |
| One  | 02 | A1    |
| One  | 02 | B1    |
| Two  | 01 | A1    |
| Two  | 01 | B1    |
| Two  | 01 | B2    |
| Two  | 02 | A1    |
+------+----+-------+
```

I did the following to geet the number of unique `Nr` values per Type:

```
DFGroup = df.groupby('Type')['Nr'].nunique().reset_index()
```

This works fine:

```
+------+----+
| Type | Nr |
+------+----+
| One  |  2 |
| Two  |  2 |
+------+----+
```

but now I would like to add another column to `DFGroup`that contains the size of each group like this:

```
+------+----+-------+
| Type | Nr | Count |
+------+----+-------+
| One  |  2 |     5 |
| Two  |  2 |     4 |
+------+----+-------+
```

I tried:

```
DFGroup['Count'] = df.groupby('Type').size()
```

which does only give me `NAN` for each group.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = df.groupby('Type').size()
DFGroup = df.groupby('Type')['Nr'].nunique().reset_index()
DFGroup['new'] = DFGroup['Type'].map(s)

print (DFGroup)
  Type  Nr  new
0  One   2    5
1  Two   2    4
```

Better is use [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) by both functions:

```
DFGroup = df.groupby('Type')['Nr'].agg([('Nr', 'nunique'),('Count','size')]).reset_index()
print (DFGroup)

  Type  Nr  Count
0  One   2      5
1  Two   2      4
```